# Simple Modular Arithematic with Negative Numbers

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If given an equation in the form:

```
3 = x mod 13
```

I know that I can generate a solution set by doing:

```
X = 13q + 3
```

And solving for x with incrementing values of q.

But what if 3 was a negative number instead? How would I manage to find possible solutions for x?

Comment: It would be the same thing. If you have $k\equiv x\,(\text{mod}\,13)$, then $x=13n+k$, where $n$ and $k$ are *any* integers.

Comment: Even if k is negative?

Comment: Yeah, they can be *any* integers.

Comment: For example, $q = -7$. Then $13q + 3 = -88$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean $x=3($mod $13)$, which has a solution set as you mentioned. If $3$ were a negative number you would generate a solution set the same way. Say $x=-3($mod $13)$ then $x=13q+(-3)$ or $x=13q-3$. Note that for positive integers $a,b$ with $a>b$, $b($mod $a)=-(a-b)($mod $a)$.

Comment: You can imagine a positive modulo as counting up, beyond the closest multiple, while a negative modulo as counting back, before the closest multiple.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!